# Wpf change control location via .X and .Y

Tags: c#, wpf

Since I first start using WPF my problem was how to change a control location and I couldn't find anything beside `.Margin = new Thickness(...)`, the problem is that this function isn't like the old .X and .Y.

Is there any way to change a control location on the X and Y axis in place of the old Thicnkess function ? Also I want this by code because my buttons are created dynamically.

Example:
If I have a button called mybutton how do I change his location like this:

```
mybutton.X=...;
mybutton.Y=...;
```

Comment: This is a Very Bad Idea™

Comment: So I should better remain to the old Thickness ?

Comment: No, changing controls by pixels in WPF. The point of WPF is scaling to screen sizes.

Comment: Yeah but I'm trying to make a application that simulate lists and that thickness isn't cooperating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Canvas` element is the only layout control that I can think of that uses X and Y coordinates

Example:

```
Button button = new Button { Content = "StackOverflow" };

Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Children.Add(button);
Canvas.SetLeft(button, 100); //X
Canvas.SetTop(button, 10); //Y
```

Comment: I made an entire game using this method. Check out smuckers launch on windows phone. It will give you an idea how horrible this is on performance.

Comment: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/smuckers-launch/f239dc2c-e088-47bd-8e34-9a27ffd8684f Horrible reviews, horrible graphics and horrible screen rate. This is what happens when you make a silverlight game using the above method to animate lol

Comment: Thanks, after all warnings about this method...I'll stick with .Margin.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell I appreciate the self deprecating nature of that example :)